# Go mod issue for go-linq package

Tags: go, go-modules

I am trying to implement the go mod dependency management for my project.
I have run command go mod init then go.mod file is created after that execute the go build command.
It give me following error.

```
gopkg.in/ahmetb/go-linq.v3: gopkg.in/ahmetb/go-linq.v3@v3.1.0: parsing go.mod:   
module declares its path as: github.com/ahmetb/go-linq/v3  
but was required as: gopkg.in/ahmetb/go-linq.v3
```

I don't know why this is happening and what to do

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the gopkg based import.

Search your files for references of "gopkg.in/ahmetb/go-linq.v3" and replace with them "github.com/ahmetb/go-linq/v3"